# Why gradient Tape with tensor flow make the sum of the tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'am testing gradient tape with tensorflow 2.0 and I don't understand the following behaviour
My example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

x = tf.constant(3.0)
inc = tf.constant([1.,2.])

with tf.GradientTape() as t:
   t.watch(x)       
   y = x  * inc

dy_dx = t.gradient(y, x)

print(dy_dx)
print(y)
print(inc)
```

the output results is :

```
2.2.0
tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([3. 6.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([1. 2.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

if y = x * inc the results of dy_dx is only inc so [1. 2.]. I don't understand why it returns the sum of inc ?
Thanks

Comment: TensorFlow always computes the gradient of the sum of the given target. If you want to compute the gradient of each target value with respect to each source value, then you need to compute the [`jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) (or [`batch_jacobian`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#batch_jacobian) if you work with batched data).

Comment: thanks a lot it solves the issue